# What is the best practice for timezone conversions?

Tags: php

I want to give users the option to change their timezone and display their data in that timezone. I'm currently storing a unix timestamp and would like to know what the best way to handle this conversion would be.

---

I am storing my timestamp in unix format. My concern is what function can I use to do the conversion on the presentation layer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep everything as UTC in your data store and convert at your presentation layer.

Comment: GMT and UTC are the same thing. Pass your timestamp to date function http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks Maxwell. I just found that now on PHPs site. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Store date data as GMT, and in the user prefs let them store their timezone (which is simply an offset of GMT).

Comment: Thanks bdl. What function would I use to so the conversion back to their tz?

Comment: Some regions have daylights savings time so the offset can vary with the time of year.